# Composer can't find composer.json

Tags: php, json, composer-php

When I download any Laravel project and run `composer install` it says to me:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users\gbl\My
> Documents\vertrigoserv\www\
>
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

It doesnt work with any Laravel project i try to run. There is composer.json in all the projects, but composer cant find them.

I am using Windows 10. Tried to reinstall composer few times and nothing happens.

Comment: where and how you installed laravel and where you run `composer install` I mean path ?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try installing composer with-in your project directory.
that will create composer.json in your project folder which will enable you to add whichever packages that you wish to add to this composer.json and update it.

also make sure you have added php and composer in your PATH variable

give this a try and let me know if it solved your issue.